# How to replace the foreign key entity use Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm use Entity Framework code first in my project. I have two entiy has one to multi relation:

```
public class Car
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
}

public class CarMapping
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Car Car { get; set; } 
}
```

And now I have get a `carID` and want to replace the car in CarMapping. I try to this:

```
var carMapping = DbContext.CarMappings.SingleOrDefault(m => m.ID == id);
carMapping.Car.ID = carID;
```

But it will lead to EF update Car and throw a exception said primary key cannot be change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `carMapping.Car` property will return you `Car` object. So you cannot change primary key in `Car` object.

If you want to change Car in CarMapping you should do next:

```
Car car = DbContext.Cars.Single(r=>r.ID == carID);
CarMapping carMapping = DbContext.CarMappings.SingleOrDefault(m => m.ID == id);
carMapping.Car = car;
DbContext.SaveChanges();
```